# Postman only posts to mongoose nested level 1

Tags: javascript, mongodb, express, mongoose

I'm trying to test a post to a mongoose schema that has nested fields, but I'm only able to level 1 and the first field in level 2. For example:

I have a network model that can contain multiple ip addresses and multiple subnets. When I place the query in to Postman it allows me to create multiple ip addresses and multiple subnets (great) but I can't define a type field for example?

Mongoose Schema:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose'), Schema = mongoose.Schema, ObjectId = mongoose.Schema.ObjectId;

var networkSchema = module.exports = mongoose.model('Network', {
network_id:ObjectId,
location: String,
hostname: String,
device: String,
model: String,
ipAddress: [ipaddressSchema],
subnets: [subnetSchema],
iosVersion: String,
softwareImage: String,
serialNumber: String,
});

var ipaddressSchema = Schema ({
ipAddress: String,
type: String,
});

var subnetSchema = Schema ({
range: String,
type: String,
});
```

Controller:

```
var Network = require('../models/network');

module.exports.create = function (req, res) {
var network = new Network(req.body);
network.save(function (err, result) {
         res.json(result);
});
}

module.exports.list = function (req, res) {
Network.find({}, function (err, results) {
  res.json(results);
});
}
```

Postman Query:

[image]

Postman Result:

[image]

I would like:

```
{
"__v": 0,
"location": "London Office",
"hostname": "lon-asa-01",
"device": "Switch-MLS",
"model": "Cisco 3750",
"softwareImage": "1.2",
"serialNumber": "123456",
"_id": "5510495c1d40ef965d7d1cec",
"subnets":[ 
["range" : "10.0.100.0/24", "type" : "Client" ],
["range" : "10.0.101.0/24", "type" : "Server" ],
],
"ipAddress": [
 ["ipAddress" : "10.0.100.1", "type" : "Inside" ],
 ["ipAddress" : "10.0.101.254", "type" : "Outside" ],
]
}
```

Comment: Post the form in raw format, you can format it as JSON and this way you can nest properties.

Comment: AndreiC, the "I would like" section was an example. Could you confirm the json syntax for nested properties?

Answer (score 2):

Ok, here you go:

First of all, your schema should look like this:

```
var networkSchema = module.exports = mongoose.model('Network', {
    network_id: ObjectId,
    location: String,
    hostname: String,
    device: String,
    model: String,
    ipAddress: [{type: ObjectId, ref: 'IpadressModelName'}],
    subnets: [{type: ObjectId, ref: 'SubnetModelName'}],
    iosVersion: String,
    softwareImage: String,
    serialNumber: String,
});
```

In your controller you have to insert first the entities on which your network relies on so you will have an _id to provide to the network model as reference:

```
module.exports.create = function (req, res) {
    var network = new Network(req.body);
    var ipAddress = [],
        ipIds = [];
    req.body.ipAddress.forEach(function(ip){
        ipAddress.push(new IpadressModelName(ip));
    });
    var subnets = [],
        subnetsIds = [];
    req.body.subnets.forEach(function(sn){
        subnets.push(new SubnetModelName(sn));
    });
    IpadressModelName.create(ipAddress, function () {
        // args[0] should be the error
        if (args[0]) {
            throw args[0]
        }else{
            for(var i=1; i<args.length; i++ )
                ipIds.push(args[i]._id);
        }
        SubnetModelName.create(subnets, function () {
          // args[0] should be the error
            if (args[0]) {
                throw args[0]
            }else{
                for(var i=1; i<args.length; i++ )
                    subnetsIds.push(args[i]._id);
            }
            network.ipAddress = ipIds;
            network.subnets = subnetsIds;
            network.save(function (err, result) {
                 res.json(result);
            });
        });
    });
}
```

Finally post data as raw JSON:

```
{
    "location": "London Office",
    "hostname": "lon-asa-01",
    "device": "Switch-MLS",
    "model": "Cisco 3750",
    "softwareImage": "1.2",
    "serialNumber": "123456",
    "subnets":[ 
        {"range" : "10.0.100.0/24", "type" : "Client" },
        {"range" : "10.0.101.0/24", "type" : "Server" }
    ],
    "ipAddress": [
        {"ipAddress" : "10.0.100.1", "type" : "Inside" },
        {"ipAddress" : "10.0.101.254", "type" : "Outside" }
    ]
}
```

The code in this example is just for demonstrating a approach you can use and it is not conforming to the best practices.

Comment: AndreiC, thanks for the thorough explanation! I've got a lot on at the moment so will get back to this in time(hopefully soon). I can confirm that if I run the raw json within the mongo shell that it adds the records as desired, albeit as embedded documents and not referenced collections.

Comment: I'll next tackle the controller.

Comment: this worked! now how do you get the returned JSON to show the nested objects and not just the ObjectIds?